# Can't create Xamarin UWP project in visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, uwp

Im a beginner in Xamarin and tried to create a new project for UWP in Visual Studio 2015. I receive following error, how can I fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might also want to check if you have the latest version of the nuget extension. Although it should get updated automatically.

1. Go to Tools -> Extensions and Updates
2. On the top right, search installed for nuget.
3. Select nuget package manager from the result.
4. Ensure, "Automatically update this extension" checkbox is checked.

Also, click on "Updates" on the left to see if an update for nuget is available for you.

Answer (score 1):

Goto Tools-> NuGet Package manager -> Manage Package for Solution -> Microsoft.NETCore.Universal Windows Platform -> update latest version

and try again

Regards
Vinoth.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to install UWP tools, to do so, create new project -> Windows - > Universal, as attached.

Or you can download it separately from [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk)

[image]